# wordpress page very slow - huge initial wait time

Tags: wordpress, performance, dns, hosting

have a new Wordpress site - theme has been customized but nothing changed in a big way, no extra plugins really.

Right from the off the page was taking ages to load as can be seen in the grab below. now *could* this be a problem with the theme? and the customization of it? personally i thought that it was more likely to be hosting? DNS?

any thoughts?

[long wait time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr4Lh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr:

**Your page is loading too many files at the same time. And The page is not cached.**

---

Long Version:

**1- You have too many script files (45 of them)**

**Each script file** is like a **mini program** that your visitors need to **download and process** in order for your page to display.

**Each of those script files** needs to be **parsed and processed**. You have 45 of those. **It takes time to process them**.

**Script files “hog” the browser**. This means that they demand the browser’s full attention by default – **unless they are marked as asynchronous.**

“*asynchronising*” scripts is a **fancy way of saying that you instruct browsers to load other elements on the page while they process the script file**

**So, what should you do about scripts?**

The best practice is to **use the least amount of scripts possible**. **Be aware of how many scripts the plugins / themes you use require**. Not all code is created equally and sometimes you should **just avoid bloated plugins / themes.**

Once you’ve **cut down on unnecessary script files**, you should then proceed to **combining what ever script files you ended up with**.

This sounds fancy, I know, but it’s really nothing more than **merging the contents of the separate scrip files into fewer file**. There are **plugins that can do that for you** or you **can do it manually**, although the **latter requires a bit of knowledge** to make sure things still **work as intended.**

After doing that, you need to make sure you either **“async” the script file(s) that you end up with** or **make sure it loads after your content** – *near the bottom of the page*

———————————————–

**2- You have too many CSS files.**

CSS files are just files that **contain information that tell the browser** what to do with the **content on the page**. Things like **how big the text should be or what color the header should be.**

*Treat them in the same way that you would treat script files I mentioned above.*

**Reduce any bloated stuff** you don’t need, then **optimize and combine what you have left at the end**. Again, there are **plugins that can do this for you or you can do it manually.**

*Much in the same way that script files “hog” the browser, CSS files also require full attention until they are fully downloaded*

The difference is that you **can’t “async” CSS files** – you can put them at the bottom of the load order – near the footer – *but that opens another can of worms.*

———————————————–

3- Too many requests.

This is an exaggerated analogy, but it drives the point home.

Imagine this,

You have a grand party and you want to order 100 pizzas, so you call the pizza shop. Now one of two things can happen.

A- you call / **order pizza #1** / hang up / call again / **order pizza #2** / hang up / call again / **order pizza #3** / hang up / ……etc until you get to pizza #100

Or

B- you call / **order 100 pizzas** / hang up / done.

You can obviously tell that the later is a lot less trouble / much faster.

Your page has +120 separate requests. Each request is an item **(can be a script file / or a css file / or an image / or a font file)**

Your page is currently using method A from the analogy above.

**The goal is to reduce the number of calls (or http requests) – More like method B**

*Reducing / combining your script files as I mentioned above will help cut down your requests. I should also note that you need to keep the number of fonts to the minimum.* You don’t really need more than 1 – 2 fonts. Images can be combine using CSS sprites

---

4- After you do all of the above, you need to get familiar with caching

**You are not serving cached pages.**

*When a user visits your a page on your website,* your server has to “construct” it from all the different sections of your database / php files and that takes time.

Meet Caching!

**Caching is like a xerox machine**. if you have a xerox machine, you can just make a copy of the document and serve it almost instantly.

**Serving dynamic content without caching is literally like typing the whole document all over again** – even if you already have the content memorized – every time it’s requested – **it takes more time.**

There are many great caching plugins for WordPress. Be sure to check them out.

Comment: wow ok thanks for that! i'll get started :-)

so...is this a bad theme that's being used? or is this kind of tidying up always necessary?...as i say, i've not really done much to the base theme files apart from changed text and images....